# How do I dynamically call a page/post author into the meta data?

Tags: post-meta

I would like to dynamically call a page/post Author, into the meta data, stored within the  tags.

Referring to a [WordPress Codex Article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress), I see that you can statically insert an Author as follows:

```
<meta name="author" content="Harriet Smith" />
```

I thought that I may be able to use something like the below code, in order to dynamically call the Author.  Unfortunately, this did not work:

```
<meta name="author" content="<?php bloginfo('author'); ?>">
```

Is anyone aware if this is possible and if so, how I could go about achieving this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Add this code to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function my_wp_head_action() {
    // must be a single post/page
    if( is_page() || is_single() ) {
        $post = get_post();
        $author = get_user_option( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
        echo '<meta name="author" content="'. esc_attr( $author ) .'" />';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_wp_head_action' );
```

Or, if you really want to control a position of your meta line within `<head> ... </head>` block, modify `header.php` template, and put this code, where you want it:

```
<?php
if( is_page() || is_single() ) {
    $post = get_post();
    $author = get_user_option( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
    echo '<meta name="author" content="'. esc_attr( $author ) .'" />';
} ?>
```